# From 2D to 3D drawing

Tags: loops, 3d, drawing, processing

I've trying to make a 3D drawing, all that I got is drawing in 2D, as you will see in my code below, I'm trying to get the lines being drawn in 3D, with depth, but I can't find a way to do it without using boxes or already 3D figures that don't move at all. 
Here is my code so far:

```
import peasy.*;    
static final int Lin =100;

//Loop Vintage
float t;
int x,y,z,a,b,c;

//Camera 3D
PeasyCam cam;

void setup ()
{
  background(20);
  size(800,600, P3D);
  //Distance of Camera
  cam = new PeasyCam(this, 1000);
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(1);

   //Loop Vintage
  Floop();  
}

void Floop()
{ pushMatrix();
  translate(CENTER,CENTER,CENTER);
  rotate(0);
  for(x=0;x<Lin; x++)
    line(x1(t+x),y1(t+x),x2(t+x),y2(t+x)); 
  popMatrix();
  t++;
}

//Loop Vintage
float x1(float t)
{
  return sin(t/10) * 100 + sin(t/5) * 20;
}
float y1(float t)
{
  return cos(t/10) * 100;
}
float x2(float t)
{
  return sin(t/10) * 200 + sin(t) * 2;
}
float y2(float t)
{
  return cos(t/20) * 200 + sin(t/12) * 20;
}
```

As you can see, you'll need peasyCam to see any improvement. This code draw an "hyperboloid of one sheet" like figure, is not that perfect but is the closest geometric form that I found. I've trying to do draw it (or the lines re-drawing it) in 3D, if you have any idea that can help me, will be appreciate, 
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really sure what your question is? What did you expect this code to do? What does it do instead? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: I don't know if you tried the program, but it draw an hyperboloid of one sheet in 2D, the lines are in an specific pattern that makes it feel that is in 3D, but if you use peasyCam you'll see that is not, is just an illusion from the pattern, I tried to draw lines in 3D but I got a lot of problems, because you need Vectors for this, it wasn't to hard to make a simple geometry form in 3D, but the problem is moving the lines, [Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1GKvger8CbA) to get an idea what I'm trying to do here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not sure what you're asking. You're only ever giving your line 2D coordinates. If you want something in "true" 3D, you're going to have to use 3D coordinates. My best advice is to get something simple working, like a single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see what your problem is, you want it to draw out a hyperbole, but want it done in 3D.

Try switching `line` for `triangle` (it will require 2 extra parameters), or `sphere` (which will require the radius.

That should do the trick hopefully.